# Text Editor is edited in a particular field is written as shown below

Tags: java, file, terminal

I have a text file that contains some lines, for example:

```
hbcdefgg001asdfn    
hasezahg002ehea     
jasehaah003dcdn    
abcdefgh006ahdh
```

The lines follow a set format, so for example:

1. the first 8 characters need to be letters
2. then the next 3 characters are an amount,
3. followed by a 4 letter code.

The last line contains a total of the amount of the last rows.  I now need to replicate the first 3 lines programmatically for say a 10 times and re-input the last line with the new total amount.

Am wondering what do you think is the best way to manipulate each of the lines? The positions of each letter/amount/code are fixed.

Comment: What will be the format for the last line? Doesn't the total cross the 3 character limit you have?

Comment: Are there blank line between the lines? In your input the positions are *not* fixed.

Comment: Hi @KDM, yes it would if you exceed a total amount of 999.  In reality the file is more complex but I just listed a simple example.  Let's assume I had to replicate 10 times and the amount won't exceed 999 then :)

Comment: Your example breaks your desired file format. The first two lines only contain 7 letters at the beginning.

Comment: Hi @Tichodroma, there are no blank lines between the lines :)

Comment: Hi @SebastianS., correct! Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Use shell tools: `seq`, `head`, `cut`, `awk`, `tail`, and `sed`.

The input file:

```
$ cat so.txt 
hbcdefgX001asdfn
hasezahX002ehea 
jasehaah003dcdn
abcdefgh006ahdh
```

Print the first three lines 1,000 times:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1000)
do
    head -3 so.txt >> so-long.txt
done
```

Calculate the sum:

```
$ sum=$(cut -b9-11 < so-long.txt | awk '{sum += $1}; END {print sum}')
```

Replace the sum in the last line and append it to the output:

```
$ tail -1 so.txt | sed "s/^\(........\)\(...\)/\1${sum}/" >> so-long.txt
```

Now `so-long.txt` contains 6,000 lines, the last five being:

```
$ tail -5 so-long.txt
jasehaah003dcdn
hbcdefgX001asdfn
hasezahX002ehea 
jasehaah003dcdn
abcdefgh6000ahdh
```